# Skimage SimilarityTransform spoils image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-recognition, scikit-image

I have a code which recognizes faces on images (dlib implementation, 68 points)

I want to rotate a bit some images but after a get following trouble: my image becomes somehow spoiled

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import transform as tf
img = io.imread(f)
tform = tf.SimilarityTransform(rotation=np.deg2rad(10),translation=(10,12))
img = tf.warp(img,tform)
```

I plot image with 2 ways:

```
plt.imshow(img) #the right picture (matplotlib)
win = dlib.image_window() #the left picture (dlib)
win.set_image(img) #the left picture
```

As you can see dlib image is broken. Also algorithm which can find facial keypoints stopps working.

Without SimilarityTransform dlib works correctly.

Help me please! I want to rotate an image and to pass it to dlib

[image: the prolem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I simply needed to convert image with img_as_ubyte

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
img = img_as_ubyte(tf.warp(img,tform))
```